# Ruby IE win32ole - how to get status code of a page?

Tags: ruby, win32ole

how to get the status (200 OK, 404 NOT FOUND etc.) of the last page fetched by an IE instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Ruby net HTTP library:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html